# DNS subdomain problem - Hover.com

Tags: domain-name-system, ip, domain-name

I use hover.com to manage my domain names.  I have having a huge problem with setting a sub-domain to a specific IP address:

I want the sub-domain on a particular domain name that I have.  I set an A type record for that sub-domain and pointed it towards the IP address; it is not working at all.

The thing that is confusing me is that when I set the IP address to a sub-domain on a different domain name it works just fine.  Also, I have since deleted the DNS record from the domain that it happened to work on, and when I type that address into a browser it still resolves to the IP I had it set to.

I am not sure what is going on at all.  If this seems confusing I am sorry, but I am very confused about the whole thing myself.  If any clarification is needed, just ask and I will try to clear things up.

Comment: Maybe show some data: Actual DNS records, etc....

Comment: You need to describe what you are actually trying to do. The primary message from your question is that you are confused.

Answer (score 1):

you also have to configure apache to recognize the request and redirect it to an available(!) website(directory) on your server.

Note: Usually setting/changing DNS records take a couple of hours until they work. Maybe your problem is also related to this.

Comment: Check that the A record is available from all your athoritative servers.  Until it is you may get false negatives on lookups.

Answer (score 0):

Without having the domain, I am assuming you've setup your A record correctly, DNS has a caching system which means all non authoritative servers will hold on to your old info for the time specified until the TTL(time to Live) hits. Some servers ignore the TTL completely and update when every the owner company set.